# Unable to stub redis in rspec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocking, redis, stub

I'm trying to stub redis using the [mock_redis](https://github.com/causes/mock_redis) gem for my rspec tests.  My rspec config looks like this:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ... various rspec config options ...

  config.before(:each) do
    redis_instance = MockRedis.new
    Redis.stub(:new).and_return(redis_instance)
    Redis::Store.stub(:new).and_return(redis_instance)
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, I'm still seeing gets and sets being sent to my actual redis instance, and if I kill redis, then my tests all fail.  I tried adding a breakpoint, and I do see that this block of code is properly being executed.  I also confirmed that from within the scope of this `before` block, both `Redis.new == redis_instance` and `Redis::Store.new == redis_instance` are true.

Does anyone have any insight as to why this isn't working for me?  I'm open to alternate approaches for stubbing/mocking redis as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like passing a block instead of a value to `and_return` makes it work, though I'm not sure why.  e.g.:

```
Redis.stub(:new).and_return { redis_instance }
Redis::Store.stub(:new).and_return { redis_instance }
```

Answer (score 4):

I am also having a problem with mock_redis. I found fakeredis https://github.com/guilleiguaran/fakeredis which decided my problems.